# SQL Azure data synchronisation and maintaining the history of the database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

I have an on-premise database. At the same time I have the database on cloud. When the on-premise database gets updated the SQL Azure database should also get updated. Only the changed fields should be updated. The rest should remain the same. How can this be achieved in minimal time?

Answer (score 0):

There is a No code solution called Data SYNC CTP2 but you need to request access which unfortunately stopped for now. (http://connect.microsoft.com/sqlazurectps)

You could try using SYNC framework. Have a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/08/31/sql-server-to-sql-azure-synchronization-using-sync-framework-2-1.aspx

Comment: hey paras thank you.I checked out that article.I can achieve the synchronisation for the tables containing 500 to 1000 records.but the on i m working on has got some 1 million above records.when i do the same synchronisation i m getting an time out error.is there any way to synchronize large databases

Comment: As JuneT mentioned - check out this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/09/24/how-to-sync-large-sql-server-databases-to-sql-azure.aspx

Comment: Also it may take some time to synchronize your data - you will need to test it for your app. I suggest migrating the database first and then synchronize the changes - is it viable for you?

Comment: Also if you have not kept your worker role and SQL Azure in the same datacenter - that may help decrease the total time taken to synchronize. But still you cannot rule out the network latency time between SQL server <-> SQL Azure synchronization. HTH

Comment: hey paras checked out the article.helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

just a note. Neither Sync Framework or Sql Azure Data Sync does column level change tracking or synchronization. When a column in a row is changed, the entire row is sent during synchronization.

As Paras mentioned, Sql Azure Data Sync is in CTP stage (CTP2 now, with CTP3 supposed to come out this summer).

Sync Framework 2.1 however already supports synching with Azure.

check out [Synchronizing with SQL Azure using Sync Framework](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/synchronizing-with-sql-azure-using-sync-framework/)
 for links to various walkthroughs/samples

Comment: hey June,i worked out the sample synchronisation using sync framework.but my on premise database is about 50gb.i need to migrate that database to azure and maintain synchronization with sql azure database.how can that be achieved?

Comment: unfortunately, there is no easy way to initialize the sync replicas. have you looked at this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/09/24/how-to-sync-large-sql-server-databases-to-sql-azure.aspx 

you need to set the MemoryDataCacheSize,  ApplicationTransactionSize  and the CommandTimeout to avoid timeouts and throttling.